# What is the minimum java version required for facebook-java-business-sdk API 3.2.2

Tags: java, facebook-marketing-api

We are trying to update Facebook java business SDK, the problem is we are using old java version I.e. 1.7.0.11 now we want to update Facebook java business SDK API to 3.2.2 
And there are other applications which will get impacted if java version is changed to too much high

So what is the minimum java version that is required to execute this Facebook API?

I have tried searching online couldn't find above minimum java version, all I find is document about changes API or about API itself

Please any little help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum JDK version *1.8.0_25*. You can see this in the `manifest.mf` file in the `META-INF` folder in the `facebook-java-business-sdk-3.0.0-sources.jar` file in the [Maven repo](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/facebook/business/sdk/facebook-java-business-sdk/3.0.0/).

Comment: Thanks @entpnerd I checked manifest of 3.2.2 and got the version.